# Oracle rownum 1 not working

Tags: database, oracle

I have got problem with oracle just create simple select with limit but oracle havent got this function so i wrote something like that

:

```
     select b.strdir,b.num, b.value, b.time  

          from mytable b
         where b.dev_id = 223
           and b.cur_id = 23
           and b.time=(
                select xx.time from mytable xx
                where xx.dev_id = b.dev_id and xx.cur_id = b.cur_id and xx.nom = b.nom
                and rownum=1
                order by xx.time DESC
               )

         order by b.strdir nulls first;
```

but it is not working plz help :/

Comment: What do you mean by not work?
If you run the inner query alone, what does it do?

Comment: its working but not as i need i need only one max time as one row

Answer (score 4):

This type of query is best handled using the first/last aggregate functions (also known as "the keep clause"), although I haven't tested the query.

```
select max(b.strdir) keep (dense_rank last order by b.time) strdir
     , max(b.num) keep (dense_rank last order by b.time) num
     , max(b.value) keep (dense_rank last order by b.time) value
     , max(b.time) time  
  from mytable b
 where b.dev_id = 223
   and b.cur_id = 23
 group by b.nom
 order by strdir nulls first
```

http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2012/09/keep-clause.html

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle assigns rownum AFTER a row passes the predicate, so your where clause will never let anything through. The canonical way to select TOP n in oracle is:

```
select * from ( <your statement> ) where rownum <= N
```

Comment: But if im doing it like that `and b.time=(select * from(
                    select xx.time from mytable xx
                    where b.dev_id = b.dev_id 
                    and xx.cur_id = b.cur_id 
                    and xx.nom= b.nomination                                      
                   ) where rownum = 1)` it isnt working :/ because database cant see b identifier into select ?? plz look i have got select in select in select so oracle dont see b into 3rd select

Comment: My error : ORA-00904: "B"."NOM": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 40

Answer (score 1):

To get the dev_id, row_id pair with the most recent time use:

```
 select b.strdir,b.num, b.value, b.time  
      from mytable b
     where b.dev_id = 223
       and b.cur_id = 23
       and b.time =(
            select max(xx.time) from mytable xx
            where xx.dev_id = b.dev_id and xx.cur_id = b.cur_id 
              and xx.nom = b.nom --> not sure this line is necessary
           )
     order by b.strdir nulls first;
```

Note that at the time `ROWNUM = 1` is applied, the the `SORT BY` clause is ignored, because `SORT BY` is done *after* the `WHERE`. The solution is to use `MAX(time)` is a subquery to find the latest time.

Also be aware of the risk of returning duplicate rows, in the case where it's possible to have rows with identical `time`values. One possible solution for this is to use a `SELECT DISTINCT` in the outer SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select b.strdir,b.num, b.value, b.time  

      from mytable b
     where b.dev_id = 223
       and b.cur_id = 23
       and b.time=(
            select max(xx.time) from mytable xx
            where xx.dev_id = b.dev_id and xx.cur_id = b.cur_id and xx.nom = b.nom

           )

     order by b.strdir nulls first;
```

this is good version ? **max(xx.time)**